# how to use auto scroll in view pager along with manual slide of images

Tags: android

I am working on view pager which contain images. I have implemented two options in view pager. User can scroll images and images are scrolling automatically as well. Now the problem is both the funcitonalities effecting each other. At the start of activity auto scroll starts but if let I scroll manually as well and reached to the 4th image in view pager but auto scroll funcitionality takes back me to 2nd image of view pager.

What my requirement is if I scroll manually and reached at 3rd position, auto scroll should start from 3rd position and go to 4th position.

My code for manual scroll is  :

```
  _mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.imageviewPager);

 _adapter = new ImageViewPagerAdapter(getActivity(), list);
 _mViewPager.setAdapter(_adapter);
 _mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
 mIndicator.setViewPager(_mViewPager);


   mIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            //    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Scroller is called 1:   " + item_count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Scroller is called 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Scroller is called 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

And code for auto scrolling of images is below, I have used handler to make the loop logic.

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            _mViewPager.setCurrentItem(item_count);
            sizeOfImages = globals.getImagesUrl().size();

            if (item_count == sizeOfImages) {
                reverse = 1;
                item_count--;
            } else {
                if (reverse == 0) {
                    item_count++;
                } else {
                    item_count--;
                    if (item_count == 0) {
                        reverse = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
        }
    }, 3000);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You need to set `item_count` in the `onPageSelected()`. Depending on the desired behavior, you might need to add/subtract 1, based on the current direction.

Comment: I already tried that but that further made my job tuffer, if implement this logic then item_count incremented two times, one with manual slide and one with auto slide

Comment: Don't increment `item_count` there. Set it to `position`: `item_count = position;`.

Comment: Okay , thanks a lot, it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
mIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        //    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Scroller is called 1:   " + item_count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Scroller is called 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       **add this line in listener** 
       mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Scroller is called 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

or use this library

`https://github.com/linsea/AndroidImageSlider`

Comment: I tried but it did't worked, working same as before :(

Comment: Could you help me with any working demo or tutorial .